Curious patterns when ordering odd integers by their "closeness" to being a perfect number
This is my first time posting here. I’ve been fascinated by the concept of odd perfect numbers and decided to explore a related idea. I conducted a small experiment:
I took all odd numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 and attempted to rank them by how “close” they are to being a perfect number. Specifically, for each odd integer $n$, I calculated the difference between the sum of its divisors $\sigma(n)$ and $n$ itself, and then considered the ratio of this difference to $n$. Using these ratios as a metric, I sorted all odd numbers in ascending order of their “closeness” to perfectness (i.e., how small the difference ratio is).
What I found was quite intriguing: when plotted, these values seem to form several patterns resembling logarithmic curves. It’s as if multiple “log-like” patterns emerge from the data visualization.
Here is an example of what I’m seeing:

I’m curious if this observation could be of any theoretical interest. Has anyone studied such distributions or patterns before? Could these findings be potentially useful in understanding the structure of odd integers’ divisor functions or in shedding light on the elusive odd perfect numbers? Any pointers or insights would be greatly appreciated.

The function you are looking at $h(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ is sometimes called the "abundancy" or "abundancy index" of $n$. This function has been studied a lot. Recent papers which examine aspects of its behavior include this paper of mine and most recently a nice paper by Aslaksen and Helmer's "Linear support for the prime number sequence and the first and second Hardy–Littlewood conjectures" (which doesn't seem to have an easy available online copy unfortunately). The  patterns you are seeing are coming from two different but related behavior.
In particular, $h(n)$ is bounded above by $H(n)=\prod_{p\mid n} \frac{p}{p-1}$ where the product is over primes which divide $n$.
The "upwards" patterns are likely coming from taking a repeated power of a prime. For example, if one looks at $3^k$ then $h(3^k)$ gets closer and closer to 3/2 as you increase $k$. So one will get an upwards curve at numbers from $3^k$, and a similar one for $3^k 5$, or $3^k 7$. Similarly, one will have a family from $5^k 3$ and so on. The downwards families are coming from increasing a single prime factor. For example, if one looks at $3p$, then $h(3p)= (4/3)\frac{p+1}{p}$ which gets closer to $4/3$ as $p$ gets large.
That said, there are more such curves in your data than I would expect just from these two types, so it is possible something else is also going on in your picture.

Since some people don't like to link to non-freely available content, I didn't edit in a link, but I'll leave in a comment the DOI 10.7146/math.scand.a-143425 for the paper Aslaksen and Helmer - Linear support for the prime number sequence and the first and second Hardy–Littlewood conjectures that you referenced.

I suspect that the "more" come from the absolute value.

Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and the references. I really appreciate your insights!

While the downward curves of a form like $3p$ have a lot of elements, your example of an upward curve like $3^k$ would generate only very few points in the interval OP plotted. $3^k5$, $3^k7$, etc and $5^k$, $7^k$ etc will each yield a different curve so I don't think these examples explain the upwards curves in OPs picture.

@quarague Yeah, very good point. And that very dense upward curve starting at the far left corner is particularly hard to explain this way. I don't unfortunately have time right now to replot the OP's picture and see what numbers are producing it. There's likely some sort of important family here I'm missing.

@yook Can you try to narrow down what numbers you are seeing in that curve that starts on the lower left and then trends up? I haven't had the time to plot as far out or as narrowly as you have, but in this less far out plot it doesn't seem to have shown up yet https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrrQVHdna04o24nHlpNYuRMgUQGFy_m3/view?usp=sharing .

Thank you very much.
Here is the code (above) and below is the CSV file containing the top 2000 odd numbers sorted by their “closeness” to being perfect:
Code:
https://pastebin.com/Ve8eik6X
CSV (top 2000):
https://pastebin.com/Uxw8etPR

@JoshuaZ That very dense upward curve appears to be $n=3^2\cdot5\cdot7p$, e.g. $n=198765=3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot631$ where $h(n)\approx1.98409$. Of odd $0<n<10^6$, 2015 have $1.929<h(n)<2.071$, so OP, who plotted 2000 points, must've imposed limits close to those.

@JoshuaZ Correction: $1.949<h(n)<2.051$.

@RosieF That confuses me since that should be a downwards family.

@JoshuaZ OP plotted $|h(n)-2|$; taking absolute value folded the plot about the line $y=0$ (the bottom edge of OP's plot).

@RosieF Ah, that makes sense. So in this picture both the upwards and the downards curves are both coming from the families of the form $mp$ for different values of $m$.
